# How to upload to google app engine just one python script (not all project folder)?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm newbie in Google App Engine.

I can't found information about appcfg.py, which explains how to specify a few files to uploading. When I'm executing

```
appcfg.py update .
```

it's uploading all project folder and it takes a lot of time.

How can I upload to server only `main.py`, for example?

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Probably, best way is to test project at localhost.

Comment: oh there is no discussion on that. why would you test a project online?

Comment: Because at localhost I have blank html and no errors. And at server I have logs with all the info.

Comment: blank html? logs are in the console...

Comment: Yeah, displayed html is empty. And console does not contain any error message. I'm at Ubuntu and I start dev_appserver.py with --debug flag.

Comment: that is weird. i suggest you to ask a new question for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't only upload part of the application, you upload the entire application at once.